# View/compare revision differences in new Google Docs document

Tags: google-drive

In the new version of Google Docs is it possible to view/compare revision differences as you used to be able to do to see the changes highlighted.

I know you can view previous versions but what I want is to see the individual changes highlighted by the user that made them.

Comment: The infuriating thing is that when I open a document that's been changed since I last viewed in, Google offers me a button to show the changes since I last visited, which brings up a *"Changes since [date]"* screen. But that screen doesn't get its own URL, and once I refresh, both it and the button are gone forever. Dear reader: if you are comfortable with your browser's dev tools, perhaps, next time you get the opportunity, you could try clicking through that button's handler in the debugger, to see if it can be easily reverse engineered and used for comparing arbitrary revisions instead.

Answer (score 30):

The best way I found is to use named version.
You can set names for each versions and you can compare current named version with previous named version. So the step is

1. Set names to two versions you want to compare with.
2. Turn on "Only show named versions".

Then you can see the difference between specific versions.

In order to be able to visually see the highlights and strikethroughs, you need to check the *Show Changes* box at the bottom of the right-hand column, then click on the named version you wish to view.

Comment: After naming two versions and switching to "Only show named versions", I see no option to compare revisions, only to view the different revisions.

Comment: When you select a revision, the spread sheet is supposed to show the difference between the selected revision and previous revision.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for google docs.

Comment: I believe this technique still works.  Bizarrely, you need to _uncheck_ the "Show Changes" option.  This will causes the changes to appear in colored highlighting.  There will also be an "Edit N of M" indicator in the upper right hand corner, with arrows to skip to the next/previous edit.

Comment: @JessRiedel found the trick. Just UNCHECK "Show Changes", and the changes will be shown! No need to name revisions.

Comment: But seriously, you should *name your revisions*! Google says _The revisions for your file may occasionally be merged to save storage space._ See [their help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843#compare_documents&zippy=%2Ccopy-an-earlier-version)

Comment: This answer is helpful but could be clearer. Google Docs already shows changes between two adjacent revisions and what is missing is the ability to do that by picking arbitrary revisions. By naming the two revisions that are of interest and selecting the option to show only named revisions, one is able to see them adjacent to each other and thus the diff between them. However, if there are existing named revisions that sit in between the ones of interest, they will not come adjacent to each other and so this technique won't work.

Comment: +1 because it solved my problem but would be great to incorporate @haridsv's comment which gives excellent context

Answer (score 18):

This is no longer possible in the latest version of Google Docs. Please, see other answers instead.

---

**It previously worked this way:**

1. Open the document in Google Docs
2. Click the [File] menu item
3. Click the [See revision history] option
4. Check the box for the newest revision you want to compare.
5. Scroll down the list and check the box for the oldest revision you want to compare.
6. Click the [Compare checked] button to see the changes between the old and new revision entries you checked.

Added content will be block highlighted. Deleted content will have a line through it. Both will be in the color of the editor that made the changes.

Update: As discovered by [DEFusion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/3447/defusion), old documents, which I had used to write the above process, are unaffected by the new "feature" (or deletion of a feature, apparently). I failed to actually create a new document to test the process. Indeed, new documents created in Google Docs do not provide a diff function. Only browsing between newer and older versions is currently possible.

So, unfortunately, it looks like for now no diff-ing is possible.

Comment: I don't see any check boxes, nor a [Compare checked] button.

Comment: I literally opened docs.google.com and walked through a document when I wrote those. Can you please provide your operating system, browser and browser version so I can test against it? Also, can you provide a screenshot of what you see when you get to step 4? (Shift+[Print Screen} button on keyboard, paste to Paint or Seashore, save, then insert into the original question by clicking "edit" and using the image button)

Comment: @Matt Lutze: I have the same problem as ptomato; could this a browser difference? I'd like to know how to do this as well.

Comment: @neilfein Could you please post your OS and browser?

Comment: In Firefox 3.5.__, Google Chrome 5.0.__ and Safari 5.0.1 on OS 10.6 I have the proper checkboxes. In Internet Explorer 7.0.__ and Firefox 3.6 on Windows XP I have the checkboxes. I'm curious what could be different on your machines that the checkboxes aren't displaying. The problem isn't with the process, though (and I'd kinda appreciate an un-negativing the post, if possible?)

Comment: WWindows 7 Starter, Chrome 6. Specifically, I can't find the "Compare Checked" button.

Comment: In all fairness to Matt, I found a reference to the "Compare Checked" button [on the Google help forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=723270dc73a895f7&hl=en), and it sounds like what he's describing.

Comment: Now, a few minutes later, I tried this again and it works. Earlier, choosing File > See revision history was simply showing a list of the versions of the document, and now it's displaying a window where you can check off one or more versions of the document and click "Compare checked", just as Matt indicated. Anyone trying this, if it doesn't work, just try it again later. 

I upvoted Matt's answer.

Comment: Yeah, three cheers for Google. A lot of the Google Apps have a tendency to get a little temperamental. Glad it worked eventually, though -- Docs is definitely a useful tool when it works :)

Comment: This is how the old Google Docs handled revisions, the new Google Docs (ensure you're looking at a document created with the new Google Docs) simply has this menu when entering "See revision history":

<< Back to Editing << Older Newer >> [Drop down to pick revision to view] Revert to this one

Comment: Hmm, apparently the comment notification system on SE is temperamental too -- none of this discussion lit up the little envelope next to my name, so I didn't see it. Thanks for the clarification, I removed my downvote.

Comment: SE only notifies you of comments on your posts, or comments that mention you by name, @ptomato.

Comment: Does this work for you? I tried it in both Chrome and Firefox, and I don't see any "Compare checked", or check boxes after clicking on "See revision history". It just shows a pane on the right, with the list of revisions, and click on each of them gives a button to restore the document to that revision.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, This was for Google Docs 3 years ago. I think what you described is simply how they do it now.

Comment: Right, I guess the feature to compare two specific revisions is gone. Each revision can be compared with the previous, though, and this gives a hack for comparing an older revision with the current one: restore it, then restore the current one again, so that the two ones you want to compare are the top two revisions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I thought there was a way to do it again, but I can't get to Google Docs at the moment. I'll explore a little later, I guess.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR it does not work for me: after restoring revisions Google Docs shows only a single full-document change

Comment: so the only option for me was to download different versions as separate docx files and compare them using MS Word

Answer (score 16):

You can use https://github.com/larsks/gitdriver to create a git repository mirroring a google doc. In the repository is only one file stored and there is a commit for each Google Drive revision. Then, you can use commands like `git log` of `git diff` or graphical tools for showing the diff as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program.

It is a shame that people must invent such tools for Google's inability to accomodate user's workflow.

Comment: Down sides: if you export HTML, the document is all on one line, making comparison with most diff tools more difficult. Text output works better, but loses formatting information. The import loses authorship information. Also, the import is kinda slow. Still, glad to know it's an option!

Answer (score 5):

You can see differences between named and unnamed versions.
Go to File->Version history->See version history
On the right hand side, you'll see the versions. If you click on one of them, you will see above your document, on the right hand side 
[image: Total: X edits]

The total shown is the number of changes between the version you highlight and the previous one shown. There are two arrows to the right of the total for taking you from one change to the next. When only named versions are shown, you see the difference to the previous named version. When both are shown, you can click on the little triangle to the left of a version to show also unnnamed version. In that case you'll see differences between one unnamed version and another.

You can name and "remove name" for versions with the menu to the right of the version name to see differences between further away versions.

All this worked June 4, 2019.

Comment: it still works.

Answer (score 4):

This method will create a new document with the changes as suggestions.

1. In the updated document:

   1. Select the menu item: **File/Version History/See Version History**
   2. Find the version upon which you wish to base the compare/diff.
   3. Click the vertical ellipsis, and select "Make a Copy"
2. In this new copy of the document:

   1. Select the menu item: **Tools/Compare Document**
   2. For **Select the comparison document**:

      1. Click My Drive
      2. Select the original document
      3. Click **Open**
   3. For **Attribute difference to:**,  select: **<< your user >>**
   4. Click **Compare**
   5. After a few moments, the Dialog "Comparison is ready is shown"
   6. Click **Open**
3. The document will show the diff/changes as suggestions.

Comment: The "Compare Document" menu item does not appear to be present in the current version of Google Docs, either in the Tools menu or any other menu.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as of today. It looks like the "Compare documents" feature was just recently added, it says "New" right next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Adobe Acrobat, you can print the two documents to PDF files using Docs Print/Save As PDF command, then compare them using Adobe Acrobat's Compare Documents feature.

Comment: This only creates a longer process of what is already available.  OP need the changes highlighted by each user.

Answer (score 0):

Docs has "Tools -> Compare documents". This can be used. For each (from/to) version, create a new document, and then compare these documents.

This creates 3 documents (two source documents and the comparison result), that you then may want to delete afterwards. But it is possible.