# Finding the changes within a Google Doc's revision

Tags: google-drive

I can use the revision history within a Google Doc to see who made what changes, but I have to search through the entire document to see which sections were touched by each change. Is there any way to find which page or sheet was changed by the selected revision?

I've experimented with both spreadsheets and documents, and neither of them scroll to the affected area. Even worse, I made a change to page 1 followed by a change to page 2 a few seconds later, and they were included in the same revision. I was using the more detailed history.

This question is similar to [viewing or comparing revision differences in a new Google Docs document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5737/1243), but I'm not trying to compare arbitrary revisions. I just want to see what changed in the selected revision.

Comment: This is now an easy feature [as explained here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130478/138865).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until Google adds this functionality, you can't do it within the web app itself.

However you could copy and paste the data from Google Docs into two text files and then use a text-comparison tool to compare those files. Of course, this is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 8):

In Google Docs Spreadsheet I sometimes I want to see diff between two distinct dates, and there is no such native function in GUI.
Instead, I found meaning of most parameters in the URL, and changing them allow me to do what I want.

Full URL (for example): `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ver?`**`key`**`=0AktJaH0jw0i8dFJDcVhSb2lWUmdsaW0yN0gzWEgzb1E&`**`t`**`=`*`1350883825412001`*`&`**`pt`**`=`*`1347006445030001`*`&`**`diffWidget`**`=true&`**`s`**`=AJVazbU5bkWX55jnhNtlqBYdmC8rGRn7Mg&`**`gid`**`=0`

Parameters:

- `key` – document key (leave as is)
- `s` – another key (dunno what, leave also)
- `diffWidget` – header with full document link above the table (true/false)
- `gid` – sheet number (counting from zero, same values as for #gid in full view).

and, most interesting:

- `t` and `pt` – define time range in which differences will be highlighted.

  `t` (time?) is later time, `pt` (previous time?) is earlier one.

  They consist of 10 digits of UNIX time (`1350883825` for my `t`) and probably 6 digits of sub-second value (`412001` for my `t`). You can convert any time you want to unix time, append `000000` (six zeros), and put it into these parameters, and differences will be highlighted.
  You can get the Unix time stamp for any date at e.g. [onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

It's not exactly what you want, but it will help you speed up and do binary search (split time range in half each time) instead of sequential look up.

Comment: Good answer, and welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! I edited in a link to a UNIX time conversion service, as many readers don't necessarily know about UNIX timestamps.